# How to build libraries with two-way peer-dependencies in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, peer-dependencies

I have two libraries, one which makes requests and another which does logging. Both libraries require configuration from the client, which will always be using both of them.

The request library makes calls to the logging library throughout, and has it listed as a peer dependency.

The logging library has one function which calls a method in the request library to output logs. That method is free of log calls to avoid infinite loops. The logging library also has the request library listed as a peer dependency.

When I try to run `tsc` in the request library, it complains that it could not import itself. When it imports the logging library, the logging library tries to import the request library, which cannot be found. Obviously I don't want to publish each version of the request library with a previous version of itself nested inside, so installing an old version is not going to work.

I tried dynamically loading the request library within the logging library with typescript's `await import()`, but that apparently still tries to open the request library causing the error.

What is the best way to implement this kind of two-way library relationship?

Answer (score 1):

> two-way peer-dependencies in typescript?

You don't. Not in JavaScript, Not in TypeScript. Circular dependencies are not nice.

## Fix

Isolate the circularity in a third library.

Before:

```
A -> <- B
```

After:

```
A -> Common
B -> Common
```

If you can't think of the `Common`, then `A & B` really should be 1 (instead of 2)